# ClipCursor() in winapi. Can i use something similar in x11 or different library for linux?

Tags: linux, x11

ClipCursor() is in winapi. Can i use something similar in x11 or different library for linux?? I'm using SFML 2.0 to create a window, and i need to limit mouse to window area. How can i do it in linux?

when im compiling the same project to windows, i just use

```
HWND h = window.getSystemHandle(); //window is SFML sf::RenderWindowObject.getSystemHandle() returns handle
RECT r;
GetWindowRect(h,&r);
ClipCursor( &r );
```

But in linux, there is no winapi.... Maybe someone know how to do it effectivly in x11?

Comment: "limit mouse to window area" we don't do that. the user has complete freedom to switch to another program at any time.

Comment: Thats right, but i need to lock the mouse because it's a game. User can pause it, and then game will automaticly release mouse.

Comment: "then game will automaticly release mouse". Unless there is a bug, and it will not release the mouse, leaving the entire session unusable. Even if there is no bug, a program should not require any special action to leave it. Perhaps the user forgot how to pause or quit the game. Why not pause the game when the window loses focus?

Comment: For the RTS game that im making it's nessesary to limit mouse around rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [XGrabPointer](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabPointer.html). Just tested like so:

```
XGrabPointer(display, window, True, 0,
             GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync,
             window, None, CurrentTime);
```

... and it worked like a charm!